# How to fix "unexpected Identifier" for discord bots

Tags: node.js, logging, bots, discord

I try to run my bot via node bot.js and it doesn't run at all it just skips to next line as nothing happened but when I open the node program I get

Thrown:

```
node bot.js
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
```

How do I fix it I'm new to this stuff

my Code is :

```
    var Discord = require('discord.io');
    var logger = require('winston');
    var auth = require('./auth.json');
    // Configure logger settings
    logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
    logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
        colorize: true
    });
    logger.level = 'debug';
    // Initialize Discord Bot
    var bot = new Discord.Client({
       token: auth.token,
       autorun: true
    });
    bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
        logger.info('Connected');
        logger.info('Logged in as: ');
        logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
    });
    bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
        // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
        // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
        if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
            var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
            var cmd = args[0];

            args = args.splice(1);
            switch(cmd) {
                // !ping
                case 'ping':
                    bot.sendMessage({
                        to: channelID,
                        message: 'What!'
                    });
                break;
                // Just add any case commands if you want to..
             }
         }
    });
```

Before you ask, Yes I did use a tutorial but I did change all of the weird "'s

Comment: Can you verify that auth.json doesn't have any weird typos & etc? Or is there a larger error message being returned when you run the function?

Comment: Are u sure that your fail is called `bot.js ` you can write `node . ` to check if it works if it do just verify the name of the main file.